# Is notarization valid for iOS (iPhone/iPad) apps

Tags: ios, iphone, notarize

Is Notarization applicable only for macOS apps or is it required for iOS apps too ?

Comment: Wondering the same. Trying to fix error "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified" when trying to install a self distributed app. Dunno if notarization might help